# Identify 2-PIN water resistant DC Connectors for Holiday LED Lights

Tags: led, power-connector

Is there a "proper" name for the connectors shown in the pictures?  I'm trying to find "extension cords" to place the light string farther from it's DC controller and need an extra length of cable to do that.  Using an AC extension cord isn't an option, I'm trying to shield the controller boxes inside a weather-proof box.

Yes, I could splice and solder (I know how to do that) but was trying to avoid the hassle.

The connectors belong to these holiday lights outdoor use.  The link is here: https://www.acehardware.com/departments/home-and-decor/holiday/christmas-lights/9080486

The measured voltage on the DC connector is 3 volts, although it appears to be pulsed to control the LED colors.

What I'm trying to find is a way to even search for extension cords with these connectors on them.  "dc power extension cable" is far to wide a search, I was just looking for some way to identify the connectors.  I have tried and failed 3 times on amazon to obtain extension cords like this, the connectors end up being too small or have a semi-circle plug instead of the small notch shown here.

My photos include imprecise measurements for reference.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: 2 pin male connector 13mm outside ø]
[image: 2 pin female connector, 9mm inner ø]
[image: connectors coupled together, note the "o" ring]
[image: 2 pin female connector, note the single notch as opposed to a flat edge]